# Slippry slider images navigate to page other than defined href=""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my page:http://www.candoor.ca/index-1.html
The slider I used is slippry slider. Can be downloaded at http://slippry.com

If I click the banner image it loads about us page while in HTML I've this:

```html
<ul id="slippry-demo">
  <li>
    <a href="/cat_name/Commercial-Garage-Doors.aspx">
      <img src="img/commercial-industrial-doors.jpg" alt="Commercial and Industrial Doors">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cat_name/Loading-Dock-Products.aspx">
      <img src="img/loading-dock-products.jpg" alt="Loading Dock Products and Equipment">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cat_name/Roll-Up-Shutters.aspx">
      <img src="img/grilles-shutters.jpg" alt="Shutters and Grilles">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cat_name/Residential-Garage-Doors.aspx">
      <img src="img/residential-garage-doors.jpg" alt="Residential Garage Doors">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/cat_name/Commercial-Door-Operators.aspx">
      <img src="img/garage-gate-operators.jpg" alt="Commercial Operators, Garage and Gate Openers">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/about-candoor.aspx">
      <img src="img/authorized-distributor.jpg" alt="Authorized Distributor">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

without the empty div you have added it will work fine try this :

```html
<ul id="slippry-demo">
<li>
<a href="/cat_name/Commercial-Garage-Doors.aspx" ><img src="img/commercial-industrial-doors.jpg" alt="Commercial and Industrial Doors"></a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/cat_name/Loading-Dock-Products.aspx" ><img src="img/loading-dock-products.jpg" alt="Loading Dock Products and Equipment"></a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/cat_name/Roll-Up-Shutters.aspx" ><img src="img/grilles-shutters.jpg" alt="Shutters and Grilles"></a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/cat_name/Residential-Garage-Doors.aspx"><img src="img/residential-garage-doors.jpg" alt="Residential Garage Doors"></a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/cat_name/Commercial-Door-Operators.aspx" ><img src="img/garage-gate-operators.jpg" alt="Commercial Operators, Garage and Gate Openers"></a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/about-candoor.aspx" ><img src="img/authorized-distributor.jpg" alt="Authorized Distributor"></a>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That isn't empty Div. It contains the captions below slider images. I just removed text in p tag so to post question here.

Comment: okeey sorry :) , if you want to use a caption you must follow the docs :
http://slippry.com/examples/portfolio/

Comment: I've followed them, anyone can help?